# Oracle Script For Getting Long Active Sessions

Tags: sql, oracle, monitoring

Is there any script that you could provide for `v$session`? I seem to be encountering an issue in which my oracle active sessions are filled up. This is when I do a

```
SELECT * FROM V$SESSION WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```

My problem is, I need a script which could determine how long the connection was held and who was holding it? I wonder where I'm getting it. If possible, it would be really nice if I could autodial these sessions. I'd like to know how long they were held since the last command was done. Another thing to note, there is no current statement associated with the SQL sessions I'm seeing.

Comment: [Displays information on all database sessions](http://www.oracle-base.com/dba/Script.php?category=monitoring&file=sessions.sql). Other [oracle scripts](http://www.oracle-base.com/dba/Scripts.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you are looking for.

What does "how long the connection was held" mean, exactly?  The `LAST_CALL_ET` column in `V$SESSION` will, for sessions in an active status, indicate the number of seconds since the last call was made.  The `LOGON_TIME` column in `V$SESSION` will show you when the database session was initially created.  Are you looking for a different metric?  If so, can you describe the metric in a bit more detail?

What does "who was holding it" mean, exactly?  The `USERNAME` column of `V$SESSION` tells you the Oracle username and `OSUSER` tells you the operating system user on the client machine that opened the session.  Are you looking for a different metric?  If so, can you describe that metric in more detail?  For example, are you looking for the name of the ultimate user in a three-tier application?

I'm not sure what "autodial" means in this context.

Is "how long they were held since the last command was done" different than "how long the connection was held"?  If so, it sounds like you're describing the difference between `LAST_CALL_ET` and `LOGON_TIME`.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have an app that is not closing connections correctly, to identify the culprit modify your original script to:

```
SELECT username,
    program,
    terminal,
    COUNT (*)
FROM v$session
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY username,
    program,
    terminal
ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC
```

This should hopefully help you pinpoint where the connections are being used.